# Executable slower in Cygwin under Windows than in Linux in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows, fortran, cygwin, gfortran

I have Fortran code with many .f files which generate a executable. I ran the simulation and executed the software successfully in Linux (in Virtual Box). When I did the same in a Cygwin environment in Windows, it is running successfully but a few seconds slow.  The fortran code I am working on is an iterative code. each iteration ran slower  by the order of milli seconds. when I ran the whole code for 1000 times , it delayed by seconds. I used the time package to know total execution in virtual box.It gave
real    0m0.061s
user    0m0.036s
sys 0m0.020s

In windows with measure command of powershell:total execution time = 0.095 seconds

Every time Linux wins the race even though Virtual Box takes only half the cores of the processor and half the ram. Is this behavior normal or is something wrong?

Comment: You should really show at least the measurement results. Few seconds out of few minutes or few hours? What kind of code is that?

Comment: @Daniel please don't make edits which formats every word that happens to be also a tag as code. Use the code marking for code. Words like Linux and Windows deserve to be written normally and with a capital first letter.

Comment: Also it is important to show how you are compiling the code. Especially which optimization flags are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal. 
The fork implementation on cygwin is slow due to the amount of workaround to bypass Windows limitation.

Your repetitive compilation is probably wasting a lot of time during forks.

Comment: Why would a simple iterative program do any fork?

Comment: Run the code 1000 times , so 1000 forks, and may be 1000 Antivirus  check. Check with strace where the code is taking system time, it could give you additional data.

Comment: So he is running the executable 1000 times separately, instead of doing 1000 computations in one executable? That can indeed do almost anything...